# "HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output" exception when executing a bulk-delete on Swift using jClouds

Tags: java, httprequest, openstack-swift, cloudfiles, jclouds

When trying to execute a bulk-delete for objects in openstack swift using jclouds, we are getting the following exception:

```
HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output connecting to DELETE http://swift.internal.com:8080/v1/AUTH_312312_321312_3123131_5435/dummyContainer/dummyObject?bulk-delete=true HTTP/1.1
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: What version of jclouds are you using and are you trying to delete all files and the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are describing a problem with jclouds, this is a good place to start:

http://jclouds.apache.org/documentation/userguide/bug-report/

The wire log is very helpful when debugging.